# index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <ul> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <h6> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <ul> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.
```

What is the cause of these errors?

Answer (score 3):

[`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) is used to denote a paragraph of text, and it makes no logical sense to include a heading, list or form inside of a paragraph. As such, `<h6>`, `<ul>` and `<form>` are not valid children of the `<p>` tag. The only permitted content for `<p>` tags is [*phrasing content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

The only phrasing content (and the only valid children of the `<p>` tag) are `<abbr>`, `<audio>`, `<b>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<button>`, `<canvas>`, `<cite>`, `<code>`, `<command>` (obsolete), `<data>`, `<datalist>`, `<dfn>`, `<em>`, `<embed>`, `<i>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<kbd>`, `<keygen>` (obsolete), `<label>`, `<mark>`, `<math>`, `<meter>`, `<noscript>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<picture>`, `<progress>`, `<q>`, `<ruby>, <samp>,` , `<select>`, `<small>`, `<span>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<svg>`, `<textarea>`, `<time>`, `<var>`, `<video>`, `<wbr>` and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).

Answer (score 0):

Find elemnt by run this code in console

```js
document.querySelectorAll(" p * ul ")
```

```js
<CustomElement tag={"p"} />
// OR
<Text as="p" />
```

change with

```js
<CustomElement tag={"div"} />
// OR
<Text as="div" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have called mui Typography control without variant somewhere which is converted as a P tag on DOM render. either give variant or remove Typography control, it applicable for all.